# select id specified in if condition for selector

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
if($('#contact_name').val()==''){
$('#contact_name').closest('div').append('<p class="validate">name must be entered</p>');
error=true;
}
if($('#contact_add').val()==''){
$('#contact_add').closest('div').append('<p class="validate">address must be entered</p>');
error=true;
}
if($('#contact_mail').val()==''){
$('#contact_mail').closest('div').append('<p class="validate">mail must be entered</p>');
error=true;
}
if($('#contact_ph').val()==''){
$('#contact_ph').closest('div').append('<p class="validate">type your phone number</p>');
error=true;
}
```

I have to change each time the selector $('#contact_name'), $('#contact_add'),.... is there anyway that is what in the if condition the id is can I select that.....

I'm sure I can't use $(this).....

Answer (score 2):

Try this, using jQuery selector "[**starts with**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)":

```
$('*[id^="contact_"]').each(function () {
    if (this.value == '') {
        $(this).closest('div').append('<p class="validate">some text</p>');
        error = true;
    })
};
```

I used `*` to target all elements, you can replace that with `div`,`p`, or what correspond better to your elements.

Comment: That'll teach me to post a simple answer and intend to edit to improve... +1 :)

Comment: @DavidThomas, you post great answers :), now you even have a answer with 2 options... +1 to you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `each()` and a multiple selection:

```
$('#contact_name, #contact_add').each(function(){
    if (this.value == '') {
        $(this).closest('div').append('<p class="validate">some text</p>');
    }
});
```

Or, using `filter()` to select those `input`s without a value:

```
$('div[id^="contact"]').filter(function(){
    return this.value == '';
}).closest('div').append('<p class="validate">some text</p>');
```

With the latter approach you can even assign the `error` variable (if that's required):

```
var error = $('div[id^="contact"]').filter(function(){
        return this.value == '';
    }).closest('div').append('<p class="validate">some text</p>').length > 0;
```

References:

- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the desired elements like `required` then

```
var error = $('.required').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).val()) == '';
}).closest('div').append('<p class="validate">some text</p>').length > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

use as follows in your code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ttt").submit( function(){
        if($('#contact_name').val()==''){
        $('#contact_name').closest('div').append('<p class="validate">some text</p>');
        error=true;
        }
        if($('#contact_add').val()==''){
        $('#contact_add').closest('div').append('<p class="validate">some text</p>');
        error=true;
        }
        if($('#contact_mail').val()==''){
        $('#contact_mail').closest('div').append('<p class="validate">some text</p>');
        error=true;
        }
        if($('#contact_ph').val()==''){
        $('#contact_ph').closest('div').append('<p class="validate">some text</p>');
        error=true;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the id's are of form(input) elements. If thats the case, you can iterate over the input elements like this:

```
$('[id^="contact_"]').each(function () {
    if (this.value == '') {
        $(this).closest('div').append('<p class="validate">some text</p>');
        error = true;
    })
};
```